# paypal sandbox Testing payment not working

Tags: asp.net, paypal

We recently migrated our testing and production servers to ws2008 server.
Our production server payment happening.  But in testing server it throwing  **“this transaction cannot be processed”**.  Same configuration I am using in my old server it working fine.
If any SDK or something need to install. Please help. thanks

Comment: what kind of service you are using? "standard paypal"? using Instant payment notification?

Comment: I am not familiar with paypal. We are using some dll(SDK).  Our website not navigating to Paypal site.

Comment: well you need to look at the list of sdks available to work with paypal.. https://cms.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks. then check you project and see which service you are using.. on paypal they have very good samples to work with each SDK...

Comment: Our website is already integrated with paypal. Now it is not working in new server setup. Same thing is working in old server setup.  I need to know what is miss out in new server. Can you please give some idea?

Comment: do you have access to the code of your project. you might need to go and check the code. it might be missing some api credentials. check web.config of your page that is where usually we save api credentials defined. also paypal offer service uri for sandbox and for production check if your are properly switching service uri

Comment: From my project I can access and I can do all payments!Because some firewall blocking my payment process ? no error logs are creating for this.

Comment: this might be the issue. check this https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_golivechecklist and this https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the php configuration. I had a similar problem and
discovered the reason was the arg_separator.output value was "&amp"
instead of "&" which is what you need for paypal. 
Assuming you are using php you can set this value in code thusly;
ini_set('arg_separator.output','&'); this will change the value for the
duration of your script and then change back, so you have to include
it on all scripts.
Alternatively change the php.ini file.